# 'JSX' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

This is my component:

[image]

And there are two errors TypeScript is showing

[image]

How can I tell this function that it's going to be passed the **children** property which will be the JSX element or an array of JSX elements

Comment: Have you tried typing `children: React.ReactNode` instead?

Comment: 1. Don't post images of code, post text that we can copy/paste to run ourselves. This is well-covered in the help center and the tour. 2. You don't define JSX anywhere, so quite naturally it is undefined. 3. That type is not the correct type for the children prop which is `React.ReactNode` as @gqstav correctly points out, and you could have discovered this by googling "typescript react children type" or some such. 4. You can avoid having to explicitly type standard react props by typing your component as a `React.FunctionComponent` as Majid M. correctly points out in the answer below.

Comment: JSX is defined by react package, make sure you installed packages:)

Comment: to add children to the prop set, you can use the PropsWithChildren type like React.PropsWithChildren<ViewProps>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try define your component as `FunctionComponent` from `react`. It has own `children` property:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent } from 'react';
type Props = ViewProps;
export const Component: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  return <>
      {props.children}
  </>;
};
```